# How to display ImageIcons sequentially each for certain amount of time? Java, Timer

Tags: java, user-interface, timer

So let's say I have four ImageIcons,

```
private ImageIcon characterIntro;
private ImageIcon characterIdle;
private ImageIcon characterAttack;
private ImageIcon characterJump;
Timer time;
```

and they are initialized with gifs inside a constructor.

I know how to paint them on the screen using my paintComponent, however how do I make each of them appear for a certain amount of time? I would like to do the following sequence:

- display the characterIntro for 5 seconds
- after that, display characterIdle for 3 seconds
- once characterIdle has been displayed for 3 seconds, display characterAttack for 6 seconds
- after that, display characterIdle for 5 seconds
- after that, display characterJump for 3 seconds
- after that, display characterIdle for 3 seconds
- repeat sequence of everything **except** characterIntro

Normally my paintComponent looks like this, and it displays all of them at the same time:

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page); 
    page.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    if(stage1_completed && stage2_completed && stage3_completed && stage4_completed)
    {
        characterIntro.paintIcon   (this, page, char.x, char.y-10);
        characterIdle.paintIcon    (this, page, char.x, char.y);
        characterAttack.paintIcon   (this, page, char.x, char.y);
        characterIdle.paintIcon    (this, page, char.x, char.y);
        characterJump.paintIcon    (this, page, char.x, char.y);
        characterIdle.paintIcon    (this, page, char.x, char.y);
     }
}
```

How would I use `Timer` to achieve my desired effect?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a `Timer` with different delays you could create a method like this:

```
public void scheduleTask(int delay){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer.cancel();
            doSomething();
        }
    } , delay, 1);
}
```

This will run the method `doSomething` after the `delay` in ms has passed. In your `doSomething()` method you change the `ImageIcon` that should be displayed and call the `scheduleTask()` method again with next `delay`.

For implementing this I would introduce a class called `Animation` that holds one of your images and the duration it should be displayed.

```
class Animation{
    public ImageIcon Image;
    public int Duration;
    public Animation(ImageIcon Image, int Duraction){
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Duration = Duraction;
    }
}
```

With this class you can easily create a sequence of animations as an Array.

```
private Animation[] Sequence = {
    new Animation(characterIdle, 3000),
    new Animation(characterAttack, 6000),
    new Animation(characterIdle, 5000),
    new Animation(characterJump, 3000),
    new Animation(characterIdle, 3000)
};
```

Regard that I left out your characterIntro image. This will be the initialization and not part of the sequence.

In your code use a `private ImageIcon actualIcon;` object that holds the actual Image you want to display and that you change in the `doSomething()` method and a `private int actualSequenceId;` value that holds the actual animation id in the sequence array.

Now you initialize your `actualIcon` object with `characterIntro` and schedule the first image change with `scheduleTask(5000);`

And implement your `doSomething()` method like this:

```
public void doSomething(){      
    // change the actual Image and schedule next image change
    actualImage = Sequence[actualSequenceId].Image;
    scheduleTask(Sequence[actualSequenceId].Duration);

    // increment sequence Id
    if(actualSequenceId + 1 == Sequence.length) actualSequenceId = 0;
    else actualSequenceId++;
}
```

Comment: Ok so if I understand this correctly, first I type scheduleTask(5000); in my paint component. Then that calls the doSomething() method, but how would I write that method so that it stores characterIntro the first time I call it, then characterIdle the second time I call it,  etc?

Comment: I can't get the scheduleTask function to work. It gives me errors on a few lines, `Timer timer = new Timer();` needs to have two parameters (int, ActionListener) and also just FYI you are missing a closing parenthesis in the timer.schedule area

Comment: @przm If parameters are missing you are using the wrong `Timer`. Don't use `javax.swing.Timer` but `java.util.Timer`. And no there are no parenthesis missing. I checked the code.

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Collect your Icons in one table (or list)

```
p.ico = new ImageIcon[]{p.characterIntro, p.characterIdle, p.characterAttack, p.characterJump};
```

then create a thread with "what to show" logic.
Something like that:

```
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int[] idxrep = {0,1,2,1,3};
                int[] dlyrep = {5,3,6,5,3};

                int idx=0;
                while (true) {
                    lbl.setIcon(ico[idxrep[idx]]);
                    try {Thread.sleep(dlyrep[idx]*1000);}catch(Exception e){}

                    ++idx;
                    if (idx == idxrep.length) idx=1;//skip intro
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

`lbl` is `JLabel` I put in the `JPanel`, but you can't in the same way redraw current icon in `paintComponent()`

Edit:

`ico` should be declared in `JPanel` where the all "characters" exists.
The characters must be already initialized before.
`new Thread()` can be put in the constructor, or some dedicated method like `start()`

Comment: I don't understand, what is `p.ico`? and where does the `new Thread()` method go?

Comment: It is `ImageIcon[] ico` declared in `JPanel` to keep all characters available by index - for example of course.